# Make anonymous functions and other information available across requests

Tags: php, lambda, persistence, anonymous-function

I'm looking for a way to store information and things like anonymous functions to let them be available across requests, similar to how `$_SESSION` stores things, but not tied to any particular request or session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your data into:

- Databases
- Caches (e.g. memcached)
- Files (not really recommended, you should prefer databases)

What exactly is your usecase? For persistent data storage you should use a database, for some temporary things caches (as long as you need no guarantee that the data will not be deleted sometime).

For storing anonymous functions you have to serialize them first. To do so, see https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure or http://www.htmlist.com/development/extending-php-5-3-closures-with-serialization-and-reflection/

Comment: Even anonymous functions? That's what I primarily need to store in my usecase.

Comment: Ahh ok, the focus of your question is the anonymous function. To store it, the anonymous function has to be serialized first. But here is the point: You can not serialize Closures with the default `serialize` function of PHP. But there are ways to do it, see e.g. https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure or http://www.htmlist.com/development/extending-php-5-3-closures-with-serialization-and-reflection/